# best practice handling NSManagedObjects and CoreData in multiple VC's

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

i'd could use your advice on this one

i restructured my whole app, to use coreData so i'd be able to save the Main Class of my app: "FooBar"
i also transfered my complete business logic into that NSManagedObject subclass FooBar()
that's why i needed to to use some kind of convenience init, to start my own methods for calculating values and so on
here's my class definition:

```
Import Foundation
import CoreData
import UIKit

@objc(FooBar)
public class FooBar: NSManagedObject {
    
    var context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext // used for other CD interactions inside this class
    var member1 = Int()
    var member2 = Double()
    var member3:Double = 0
    var fooPack:[FooPacks] = []
    ...
    
    
    convenience init(   param1: Int16
                     ,  param2: String?
                     ,  param3: Float
                     ,  param4: String?
                     ,  param5: Float
                     ,  fooPack: NSSet
                     ,  entity: NSEntityDescription
                     ,  context: NSManagedObjectContext?
                    ) {
        self.init(entity: entity, insertInto: context)
    
        self.param1 = param1
        self.param2 = param2
        self.param3 = param3
        self.param4 = param4
        self.param5 = param5
        self.addToUsedfooBarPacks(fooBarPack)
        
        self.build()
    }
    
    func build() {
        // i do something
    }
    
    func method1() {
        // i do something
    }
```

when i initialize my FooBar class inside a viewController i do this by:

```
self.fooBar = FooBar.init(param1: var1,
                              param2: var2,
                              iparam3: var3,
                              param4: var4,
                              param5: var5,
                              fooPack: var6,
                              entity: FooEntity,
                              context: context)
```

when ever i modify any instance of this class i do this by:

```
self.fooBar.member2 = newValue
self.fooBar.build()
```

and later at a specific point (in multiple VC's) i then call to save that Instance to CoreData:

```
let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
do {
        try context.save()
    }catch{
        print("\(error)")
    }
```

with this approach i often have to deal with bugs and unexpected behaviours like:
the do block gets executed successfully, but the object has NOT been saved!?

i often hand over FooBar instances to a different ViewController and i try to save them there,
but this does not seem to be the right way to do update previous fetched objects

in my opinion, this has to do with the way i handle the context variables..
and exactly this is why i am reaching out for your advice..

What is the optimal way to handle such a situation, where i want to modify and save instances within multiple different ViewControllers?
i already learned a lot new stuff about CoreData in the last months, but i seem to miss something important here..

please help me out guys :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `persistentContainer`, it helps you setup coredata stack. `persistentContainer` has two types of context: `viewContext` and `background contexts`

With this setup we always use `viewContext` to fetch data to display on UI.
And use a `background context` to make changes, update storage...

1. What is the kind of context you passed in `init` method?
2. You should execute `context.save()` on exactly the context that you used to make changes (you passed to `init`). In this case you shouldn't pass `viewContext` to `init` and use `viewContext` to call `save()`
3. How to update and sync changes between multiple ViewControllers?
   The view controller that makes changes should call save as well. And you can use `delegation` pattern to delegate/broadcast changes to other view controllers...

Comment: thanks for your reply (y) i want to address some issues i see here...apple docs tell me that i have to use a context when doing a convinience init, otherwise i wouldn't have done so.. i prepare this statement: context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext on each VC, so kind of different instances of that context..i saw that those are indeed different context's as they have different ID's..man this is getting complicated real fast :)

Comment: ok i get what you mean, i could delegate my instances and methods back to the First VC and do all interactions over there with the exact same context i have created that instance with (y) i will try that!..and @ your questions: 1) i've passed that "normal" context variable you see in the script above..the normal: "persistentContainer.viewContext"..2) as i said on the beginning of that comment, i get that and will try that (y) thx..3) i will try to use them delegation patterns (y) ..i will have to do a lot of delegations but ok..i'll try it :)

Comment: - your suggestion was absolutely right: correct answer! - delegation is the way to go...it's working like a charm! thank you very much!